# Issue with AdMob Banner Display in My Android App

Tags: java, android, xml, ads

I am currently facing an issue displaying an AdMob banner in my Android application. Despite configuring the settings, the banner does not appear when launching the application on an emulator or a physical device.

**Problem:**
While using a test AdUnit ID, the banner displays correctly in the layout design phase but fails to appear during the actual runtime.

**Details:**

**XML code in the activity_main.xml file:**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**Code in MainActivity.java:**

```
AdView mAdView;
```

**In the MainActivity class:**

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Please share any insights or suggestions that might help identify the reason behind the absence of the banner during the application launch.